# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4

I used the Ionic 4 CLI to start a demo app that used Ionic 3.9.2. The only change I made was to import NacControler from @ionic/angular, not ionic-angular

My demo gets this error: "HomePage.html:7 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined".

I get the error whenever clicking one of the 4 ion-buttons that call functions that perform animations to svg's. e.g setNight().

If it is a matter of something loading in the wrong order I'm not sure how to fix it.

package.json per request:

```
{
  "name": "ionic-sunset",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.12.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.12.3",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~1.4.0",
    "@types/node": "~10.12.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.12.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Here's home.page.html

```
    <ion-content>

  <div class="controls">
      <button color="light" ion-button (click)="setDay()">Day</button>
      <button color="light" ion-button (click)="setCloudy()">Cloudy</button>
      <button color="light" ion-button (click)="setSunset()">Sunset</button>
      <button color="light" ion-button (click)="setNight()">Night</button>
  </div>

  <svg class="background" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 750 1334">
    <defs>
      <style>
        .cls-1 {
          fill: url(#linear-gradient);
        }

        .cls-2 {
          fill: #fefbdf;
          opacity: 0.07;
        }

        .cls-3 {
          fill: #ffda71;
        }

        .cls-4, .cls-5 {
          fill: #fff;
        }

        .cls-4 {
          opacity: 0.95;
        }
      </style>
      <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="375" y1="1334" x2="375" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#50a7dd"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <title>sunsetsvg</title>
    <rect id="Sky-2" data-name="Sky" class="cls-1" width="750" height="1334"/>
    <g id="Sun" data-name="Sun">
      <circle class="cls-2" cx="385" cy="335.7" r="315.74"/>
      <circle class="cls-3" cx="385" cy="335.7" r="180.56"/>
    </g>
    <g id="Clouds">
      <path id="Cloud" class="cls-4" d="M303.24,920.47c9.53-6.84,15.35-16,15.35-26,0-18.94-20.8-34.66-48.16-37.83,0-.2,0-0.39,0-0.59,0-28.13-29.43-50.93-65.74-50.93-31.76,0-58.27,17.45-64.4,40.65A156.9,156.9,0,0,0,116.74,844c-58.3,0-105.56,31.51-105.56,70.37s47.26,70.37,105.56,70.37c22.56,0,43.45-4.72,60.61-12.75,10.15,19.11,43.41,33.12,82.91,33.12,47.56,0,86.11-20.31,86.11-45.37C346.37,943,329,928.31,303.24,920.47Z"/>
      <path id="Cloud-2" data-name="Cloud" class="cls-5" d="M714.81,520.89c0-19.94-38.95-36.37-89.12-38.62,3.74-4.4,5.79-9.17,5.79-14.16,0-22-39.8-39.81-88.89-39.81-45.55,0-83.1,15.35-88.27,35.13-13.56-5.18-30.92-8.51-50-9.1-10.25-10.15-27-16.77-45.95-16.77-31.19,0-56.48,17.93-56.48,40,0,0.42,0,.84,0,1.26-19.2,9.08-31.53,23.07-31.53,38.79,0,27.36,37.31,49.54,83.33,49.54,20.06,0,38.45-4.21,52.83-11.23a33.31,33.31,0,0,0,35.73,9.44c11.07,22.73,38.54,38.83,70.7,38.83,20,0,38.26-6.26,51.83-16.47,8.79,9.95,23.5,16.47,40.17,16.47,26.92,0,48.74-17,48.74-38a30.14,30.14,0,0,0-1.5-9.38C688.94,551.06,714.81,537.14,714.81,520.89Z"/>
      <path id="Cloud-3" data-name="Cloud" class="cls-4" d="M303.24,351c9.53-6.84,15.35-16,15.35-26,0-18.94-20.8-34.66-48.16-37.83,0-.2,0-0.39,0-0.59,0-28.13-29.43-50.93-65.74-50.93-31.76,0-58.27,17.45-64.4,40.65a156.9,156.9,0,0,0-23.56-1.76c-58.3,0-105.56,31.51-105.56,70.37s47.26,70.37,105.56,70.37c22.56,0,43.45-4.72,60.61-12.75,10.15,19.11,43.41,33.12,82.91,33.12,47.56,0,86.11-20.31,86.11-45.37C346.37,373.53,329,358.87,303.24,351Z"/>
      <path id="Cloud-4" data-name="Cloud" class="cls-5" d="M657.61,1201.29c9.53-6.84,15.35-16,15.35-26,0-18.94-20.8-34.66-48.16-37.83,0-.2,0-0.39,0-0.59,0-28.13-29.43-50.93-65.74-50.93-31.76,0-58.27,17.45-64.4,40.65a156.9,156.9,0,0,0-23.56-1.76c-44.93,0-83.29,18.71-98.53,45.08-30.67,13.75-50.29,34.78-50.29,58.36,0,41.42,60.52,75,135.19,75,41.79,0,79.14-10.52,103.94-27,14.64,6.08,33.12,9.71,53.21,9.71,47.56,0,86.11-20.31,86.11-45.37C700.74,1223.79,683.38,1209.13,657.61,1201.29Z"/>
    </g>
  </svg>

  <div class="time">{{timeString}}</div>
</ion-content>
```

and here's homepage.ts:

```
import { Component, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import * as dateFns from 'date-fns';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    timeOfDay: Date = new Date();
    timeString: string = '12:00';

    sky: any;
    entireSun: any;
    allClouds: any;
    clouds: any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public renderer: Renderer) {

    }

    ionViewDidLoad(){

        this.timeString = dateFns.format(this.timeOfDay, 'h:mm A');

        this.sky = document.querySelector('linearGradient [offset="1"]');
        this.entireSun = document.querySelector('#Sun');
        this.clouds = document.querySelectorAll('#Clouds path');

        this.setTransitions();

    }

    setTransitions() {

        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.sky, 'transition', '1s linear');
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.entireSun, 'transition', '1s linear');

        this.clouds.forEach((cloud) => {
            this.renderer.setElementStyle(cloud, 'transition', '1s linear');
        });

    }

    setNight() {

        this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.sky, 'stop-color', '#141944');
        this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.entireSun, 'transform', 'translate(1, 2000)');
        this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.entireSun, 'opacity', '1');

        this.clouds.forEach((cloud) => {
            this.renderer.setElementStyle(cloud, 'fill', '#fff');
            this.renderer.setElementStyle(cloud, 'opacity', '0.2');
        });

    }

    setDay() {

        this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.sky, 'stop-color', '#50a7dd');
        this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.entireSun, 'opacity', '1');
        this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.entireSun, 'transform', 'translate(1, 1)');

        this.clouds.forEach((cloud) => {
            this.renderer.setElementStyle(cloud, 'fill', '#fff');
            this.renderer.setElementStyle(cloud, 'opacity', '1');
        });

    }

    setSunset(){

        this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.entireSun, 'transform', 'translate(1, 1000)');
        this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.entireSun, 'opacity', '1');
        this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.sky, 'stop-color', '#e2905a');

        this.clouds.forEach((cloud) => {
            this.renderer.setElementStyle(cloud, 'fill', '#e2c1d8');
            this.renderer.setElementStyle(cloud, 'opacity', '0.4');
        });

    }

    setCloudy() {
        this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.sky, 'stop-color', '#cecece');
        this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.entireSun, 'transform', 'translate(1, 1)');
        this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.entireSun, 'opacity', '0.2');

        this.clouds.forEach((cloud) => {
            this.renderer.setElementStyle(cloud, 'fill', '#fff');
            this.renderer.setElementStyle(cloud, 'opacity', '1');
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: can you include package.json in your question?

Comment: Do you have a function call in your component?

Comment: If you find yourself trying to set style attributes in JavaScript, you are likely doing it wrong. Use CSS style sheets and classes for capturing styles (including transformations), and apply the classes using `ngClass` based on changes in your model.

Comment: not sure if this is the issue but [Renderer](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer) is deprecated for [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2)